# What's the best practice for JDBC connection/resultset/statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I am wondering what is the best practice for the following code snippet, do I have to close all stmt and rs everytime the executeQuery is done inside each 'if' or can I do just like now, close rs and stmt at the end of runOnSqlServer, and close connection at the end fo run method? Thanks for any pointers!

```
public void runOnSqlServer(Connection con, String[] params, String db){
    try{
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    if(isVer){
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(micro_verSql);
        commonAct(rs, getParameter("isVer"), 1);
    } 
    if(isInfo){
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('"+db+"', 'COLLATION')");
        commonAct(rs, getParameter("isInfo"), 1);
    }
    }catch(SQLException){
    .....
    }finally{
    stmt.close();
    rs.close();
    }
}

public void run(CommandContext ctx) {
    try{
        ...
        runOnSqlServer(con, params, sqldb);
        ...
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }finally{
         if (con != null) con.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you should close the statement and result set after the method has completed (in the finally) but close the `ResultSet` everytime you re-user it also you should ALWAYS close the connect when you are finished with it.

edit: re-initialise

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
set = statement2.executeQuery();
```

you are setting the ResultSet "set" to a new result set. The original set is now not pointing to anything but still open waiting to be collected.

Comment: A guy told me that everytime I call executeQuery method and assign the result to a ResultSet obj, say, rs, I have to close this rs before having it assigned by another new query execution result, is that true and necessary?

Comment: If you are re-initialising it yes you should close it because it will be left open until the GC picks it up (i think). but From what i saw in your code you are not doing that so you only need to close it at the end. It is not NECESSARY but could cause problems if there is a lot that are left open

Comment: @Even, actually after looking it for a little bit, perhaps it will be better to add a null check in the second if statement for the RS if it's not null close it before setting it again

Comment: What do you mean by re_initialising? Could you give maybe a real simple sample to specify that case, thank you!

Comment: Oh, so that bascially means I still have to close the rs after executeQuery is called every single time, as long as it's not null, which in most cases is not...

Answer (score 2):

You should close all database resources:

1. in the method scope in which they were created.
2. in reverse order of creation
3. in the finally block
4. individually wrapped in try/catch blocks.

Comment: A guy told me that everytime I call executeQuery method and assign the result to a ResultSet obj, say, rs, I have to close this rs before having it assigned by another new query execution result, is that true and necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider reading this articles under "Best practices to improve performance in JDBC".

- [Optimization with Connection](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm#JDBC103)
- [Optimization with Statement](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm#JDBC109)
- [Optimization with ResultSet](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm#JDBC114)

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 7 you can use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which clearly marks the scope of your `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` and automatically closes them. Your method `runOnSqlServer(…)` could look like this:

```
public void runOnSqlServer(Connection con, String[] params, String db){
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        if(isVer){
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(micro_verSql)) {
                commonAct(rs, getParameter("isVer"), 1);
            } // rs is closed here
        } 
        if(isInfo){
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('"+db+"', 'COLLATION')")) {
                commonAct(rs, getParameter("isInfo"), 1);
            } // rs is closed here
        }
    } // stmt is closed here
    catch(SQLException){
        .....
    }
    // finally not necessary, as rs and stmt are closed automatically
}
```

As a side note: Don't use constructs like `"SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('"+db+"', 'COLLATION')"` unless you are sure `db` is not derived from user input. Concatenating strings to build a SQL statement is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using `finally` to ensure items are closed is very important.

Also, consider using a connection pool to mitigate the cost of frequently opening and closing connections.  [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) is one such package.